# Installation Node v4.1 with NVM - Permission denied

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

I have to install Node v4.1.x on Ubuntu. I have already installed it but with the wrong version. This are the steps that I followed untill now:

Installation of nvm

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git /opt/nvm
sudo mkdir /usr/local/nvm
sudo addgroup -system dev
sudo chown -R root:dev /usr/local/nvm  
sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/nvm  
sudo vim /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh
```

Editing of the file

```
export NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm
source /opt/nvm/nvm.sh
export NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/usr/local/node
export PATH="/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH"
```

Installation of Node

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/node
sudo chown -R root:dev /usr/local/node
sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/node
nvm stable
```

For installing node v4.1.x this is what I want to do:

```
nvm ls           //list of all version
nvm use 4.1.x    //if I find the correct version in the list
```

The problem is that I can't make `nvm ls` because I get

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/nvm/alias’: Permission denied
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might change NVM_DIR to:

```
 NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've installed nvm using root user (with `sudo`). When executing `nvm` commands later:

```
nvm ls
nvm use 4.1.x
```

you do this without root and you get a `permission denied`.
Generally it is not recommended to install nvm using super user.
Please check this article for more details on how to install the version manager: http://dmitripavlutin.com/install-node-like-a-boss-with-nvm/

Answer (score 0):

This can also be because of issues during the `curl` installation.
Try reinstalling using

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git-core`

Answer (score -1):

In your case issue because you gave 755 permission to the nvm folder. So it cant create folder without write permission as non root user.

Solution is you should be a root user or else give write permission for the folder to your particular user.

I too faced the same issue while installing nvm

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-94:~$ nvm install 6.0.0
```

It reported as,

```
nvm install 6.0.0 mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/ubuntu/.nvm/bin’: Permission denied
grep: /home/ubuntu/.nvm/bin/node-v6.0.0-linux-x64/node-v6.0.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory Binary download failed
```

It with the 755 permission before.

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4096 Jun 23 07:44 .nvm/
```

Then I just gave write permission for it.

```
sudo chmod +w .nvm
```

Now issue was resolved and working fine.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-94:~$ nvm install 6.0.0
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.0.0/node-v6.0.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
```